# PouchDB Replication throws error upon replication

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, couchdb, ubuntu-14.04, pouchdb

When I try to replicate a remote `couchdb` (on `ubuntu 14.04- 64 bit`) with my local `pouchdb`, I encouter this strange error.
My couchdb is proxied via `nginx` and running on `https`. Traffic from client to nginx is ssl while nginx to couchdb is simple http. Cors requests are enabled in couchdb. Nginx configuration is most similar to  [couchdb recommended](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COUCHDB/Nginx+as+a+proxy#Nginxasaproxy-nginxasSSLproxy). Sync from database is working fine however getting below errors when debugging via chrome Version 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit) .

[image]

Following is the full stack trace of the error.

`raven.min.js:2 Error: There was a problem getting docs.
    at finishBatch (http://localhost:8100/lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:6410:13)
    at processQueue (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27879:28)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27895:27
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29158:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:28969:31)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29197:26
    at completeOutstandingRequest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18706:10)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18978:7
    at d (http://localhost:8100/lib/raven-js/dist/raven.min.js:2:4308) undefineda.(anonymous function) @ raven.min.js:2(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:25642(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:22421(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:2processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:27887(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:27895$eval @ ionic.bundle.js:29158$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:28969(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:29197completeOutstandingRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:18706(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:18978d @ raven.min.js:2
raven.min.js:2 Paused in lessondb replicate Error: There was a problem getting docs.
    at finishBatch (http://localhost:8100/lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:6410:13)
    at processQueue (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27879:28)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27895:27
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29158:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:28969:31)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29197:26
    at completeOutstandingRequest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18706:10)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18978:7
    at d (http://localhost:8100/lib/raven-js/dist/raven.min.js:2:4308)`

The network logs in chrome show that some requests are cancelled

[image]

I am using couchdb version - 1.6.1 and pouchdb version - 5.3.2. 
I use following command to replicate dbs:

`myDB.replicate.from(remote_db_url,{
      live: true,
      retry: true,
      heartbeat: false
    })`

Also it would be great if someone can shed some light on heartbeat parameter .

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm not able to solve the error you describe. Maybe a full stack trace rather than a screenshot might help...

But I will try to shed some light on the heartbeat parameter: Reading the [docs](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) already helps a little. See the advanced options for the `replicate` method:

> options.heartbeat: Configure the heartbeat supported by CouchDB which keeps the change connection alive.

So let's look into [CouchDB's docs](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html#long) to see what this parameter does:

> Networks are a tricky beast, and sometimes you don’t know whether there are no changes coming or your network connection went stale. If you add another query parameter, heartbeat=N, where N is a number, CouchDB will send you a newline character each N milliseconds. As long as you are receiving newline characters, you know there are no new change notifications, but CouchDB is still ready to send you the next one when it occurs.

So basically it seems to be a polling mechanism that sends a message (f.e. a newline) every n milliseconds (where n is the `heartbeat` value you specify) to make sure the connection between two databases is still working.

Setting the value to `false` will disable this mechanism.

---

Regarding the which value can be used for this parameter:
The  [PouchDB docs](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#changes) further state, that the `changes` method has a similar parameter described like this:

> options.heartbeat: For http adapter only, time in milliseconds for server to give a heartbeat to keep long connections open. Defaults to 10000 (10 seconds), use false to disable the default.

Comment: Should we not use heartbeat for https requests?

Comment: I have added the full stack trace of the error as you mentioned